# Python wont find files?

Tags: python, image

I am trying to create code that places watermarks on an image, however Python wont find the background image. I've tried changing directories and changing the format of the name, and I keep getting [Errno 2] and [Errno 22]

```
im = Image.open("comocasto")
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. With the details you give, there is no way to help you.

Comment: Are you running on a remote location ? did you check for permissions ? .. this code you provide is without extension, did you insert the file extension on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a school permissions problem involving temporary accounts and Canopy trying to find things in a log folder.

Answer (score 1):

Either you're using the wrong filename, or you're in the wrong directory.

Comment: ive tried using different filenames and using different directories, always making sure that the directories are synced

Comment: Is your python program in the same directory as the image file?  And does the image filename have an extension, like `.gif` or `.jpg`?

Comment: yes and yes, ive tried using the image name with and without the extension

Answer (score 0):

Did you import PIL ?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
```

Verify that you are on the correct path

```
import os
os.getcwd()
Out[24]: 'D:\\'
os.chdir('C:\\')
os.getchw()
Out[27]: 'C:\\'
```

If this is not the case, them maybe you are running on a server Errno 22 means "invalid argument", do a "ls -l" to see if you have the correct permissions for reading the file.

Comment: can you explain "ls -l" i have not come across that before

Comment: on OSX and linux it is to list the files in folder showing the permissions